# Query with dates and limit (optional in DQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

i have a little bit complicated query in MySQL database.
I have relation which is on image:

[image: ERD image]

Query params: id_category, day, time
And what i want is to get ServicePoints which are:

- from seleced category
- **which in selected date and time has less visits than limit in ServiceCategory**
- grouped by ServicePoint id

In words i can say that i want to find objects, which has avaivable slots in current date.

**Best for me would be in DQL not clear sql, but of course i can convert that.**

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 SELECT sp.id
 FROM servicepoint sp
      INNER JOIN visit vt 
            ON sp.id = vt.id_service_point
 WHERE sp.category_id = categoryId    --categoryId is query param
       AND start >= startTime          --starttime is query param
       AND end <= endTime              --endTime is query param   
 GROUP BY sp.id
 HAVING COUNT(vt.id) < sp.visit_limit;
```

Comment: What if there is no visits ? Then result will be 0 service points ?

Comment: In that case, you may want to consider left outer join.